# Is it ok to take a whole day of sick leave for a medical/dentist/optometrist appointment?

Tags: human-resources, sickness

Is it ok to take a whole day of sick leave for a medical/dentist/optometrist appointment? I am thinking that it shouldn't take more than 3-4 hours, but I am also thinking that I can just take the whole day off too, but I am not sure if that's standard practice to just take the whole day off or I need to somehow justify it.

Comment: This is entirely dependent on the locale, business policies, managers, etc.

Comment: If you visit the dentist, some times it takes longer to recover than just being there.  Both mentally and physically.  The optometrist, not so much.  I take what I need, including the travel time.

Comment: You need to specify your location, the industry you're in, the number of sick days your have, etc.

Comment: Depends also on the time of you appointment... for example, this Wednesday I have a dentist appointment, which is at 10am... so I will work remotely a bit (say 8-9am or earlier), go to it (aprox 45min commute time), and then return to the office when I finish (surely around 1pm, so still half day of work)...

Comment: It would be unusual to take a *whole* day off for a routine appointment, but there are bound to be circumstances that make it necessary in some cases. There can be no general answer.

Comment: @Kingsley, at an optometrist you may have to take eye drops that won't allow you to drive for some time, for example. Depends of course.

Comment: In isolated sites like mine, it is standard procedure to take the whole day off due to commute times and long distances to specialists. We try to get 2 appointments in a day, or at least go get a flu vaccine at the drug store. I also sometimes call in to the office to answer questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It depends on the advice of the medical professionals.**

**It may also depend on the traffic and the waiting time at the doctors' office.**

Please check with your doctors first to get more accurate info about the medical procedure, and then ask your manager for the PTO you need to take.

For example, if you have your 4 wisdom teeth extracted on the same day, then it is most likely you will have to take at least 1 full day off. It is possible that you many need to take 2 or more days off.

But, if you only need a simple dental procedure like a regular cleaning, then it should probably only take from 1 to 3 hours at most.

---

However, on the days that you really have many tight deadlines at work and you only have a quick medical appointment, you may want to return to work right after that medical appointment.

Comment: >For example, if you have your 4 wisdom teeth extracted on the same day, then it is most likely you will have to take at least 1 full day off. It is possible that you many need to take 2 or more days off.

"Dental surgery" is still surgery and can be quite harsh on the body. When I had a tooth extracted I had surgery in the morning, went home and slept several hours until dinner time, drank dinner (no solids!) and checked in with the dentist, and then slept again until about midday the next day. And I still felt exhausted for a couple of days after that.

Comment: My wisdom teeth extraction (all four) involved a general anesthetic and three days in hospital.  It was many, many years ago.

Comment: What a BS answer. He can take as much sick leave as many sick hours he has available. People also need mental break not just the physical. The biggest misconception is that as long as  you aren't in pain you should be back working. Stress also adds to sickness. Stressing over working extra won't do any good. Let him rest!

Answer (score 5):

> I am thinking that it shouldn't take more than 3-4 hours

If it's going to be 3-4 hours I would do the effort to return to the office and work the remaining 3-4 hours of the office hours.

If the medical appointment is not minor, then taking the rest of the day to recover would make sense.

If it's only a minor appointment, then like I said I suggest you try to make the effort to return and work a bit so you don't fall back on your tasks.

As always, talk to your supervisor about your appointment so you can reach an agreement together that works for both parts.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Yes.

More detailed answer - if whatever you are getting done lasts much longer than 1-2 hours - take the day and put it as Sick Leave or use normal Leave.

As others have said, factors such as local Work Culture, Sick/Annual leave allowances etc. are factors and when the appointment is - but in general a 3-4 hour procedure would be a full day off, not only because you aren't gonna be super productive after the procedure, but also you need to let your body recover.

Most Doctors will be more than happy to sign a Medical Cert that tells your employer that you had a procedure and should take the rest of the day off to rest.

Answer (score 1):

What time is your appointment? Do you have to stay in a queue at the clinic?
Is it on the spot? How much time will it take to commute to the clinic and then back to work? Is it the entire day or half a day or most of the day? Also, work commitments & personal fitness to perform your duties also matter.

So if you are seriously ill, then you can take a day off otherwise you can return back to work if you finish early.